# Can a sentence or fragment without a verb be passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

Please let me know if a sentence or fragment like this is in passive voice.

> iRIDS developed by C-DAC to check red light violations.

I request you to give justification.

Comment: The following is a passive construction: *iRIDS was developed by C-DAC to check red light violations.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell, without knowing the relationship between iRIDS and C-DAC, and given that the sentence - or more likely, sentence fragment - presented looks like it came from a list.

It could be passive-voice, with "was" omitted, or it could be that "developed by C-DAC" is an adjectival phrase, or perhaps something else I haven't thought of.

Do you have a little more context for this?

Comment: Since this answer was posted, I've adjusted the question to better fit the SE model and this site.

Comment: I'm not sure that ameliorating 'impossible' to 'a little hard' is justifiable.